# Enabling PHP ERRORS doesnt apply while making changes in file /etc/php5/cli/php.ini

Tags: php, html, mysql, error-handling, syntax-error

I cant enable displaying php errors ...At the end I just put defaults and sharing it here
with hope to get some help .. In addition , when I add following piece of code to the php file errors become enabled :

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);    
ini_set('html_errors', 1);    
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Furthermore after adding that code,  it still doesnt show syntactic errors
(for example typing "whle" instead of "while")

However, I cant figure out how to make these changes through php.ini :

```
;  display_errors    
;   Default Value: On    
;   Development Value: On     
;   Production Value: On 


; display_startup_errors     
;   Default Value: Off      
;   Development Value: On       
;   Production Value: Off     

; error_reporting     
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE    
;   Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT     
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

Comment: Are you sure the **cli** `php.ini` file is the right one to edit? I assume that you're running scripts in a web context (hence the `html_errors`). You can find the right `php.ini` file via a `<?php phpinfo() ?>` script

Answer (score 3):

Adding

```
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);    
  ini_set('html_errors', 1);    
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

to a file will not work if there are syntax errors in the file as the parser finds the error before the code is run, so the error stops it turning errors on

Editing /etc/php5/cli/php.ini will not work as all you have done is add comments to the file

You would need to uncomment the setting ie remove the ; from in front of it)

```
  display_errors = on
```

It is also possible that /etc/php5/cli/php.ini is not the right file to edit depending on how your system is configured as Phil has said in comments

```
<?php phpinfo() ?>
```

will show you which php file you need to edit and if it is accessed via a webserver eg apache, then you may need to restart your webserver before any changes to that file take effect

Comment: I'd say there's a good chance that the **cli** `php.ini` file isn't the right one to edit for scripts run in a web context either

Comment: Possible, but does depend if php is running as an apache module or as an (f)cgi module

Comment: @Phil  the code I posted above is the default one, that is why there are comments I will post below the changes I did, but even after doing those changes and restarting apache2 nothing changes, as I checked by method phpinfo()

Comment: As Loaded Configuration File it shows following file: /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Comment: so edit /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini add display_errors = on save it and restart apache

Answer (score 0):

you should have

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
display_errors = On
html_errors = On
```

in your php.ini file for the php code you are using

Comment: thanks for the help :)  It works now, as Anigel and Phil mentioned I was doing changes in different file, that is why it was not working